# Move data from Oracle to Cassandra and/or MongoDB

Tags: oracle, mongodb, cassandra

At work we are thinking to move from Oracle to a NoSQL database, so I have to make some test on Cassandra and MongoDB. I have to move a lot of tables to the NoSQL database the idea is to have the data synchronized between this two platforms.

So I create a simple procedure that make selects into the Oracle DB and insert into mongo.  Some of my colleagues point that maybe there is an easier(and more professional) way to do it.

Anybody had this problem before? how do you solve it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your goal is to copy your existing structure from Oracle to a NoSQL database then you should probably reconsider your move in the first place.  By doing that you are losing any of the benefits one sees from going to a non-relational data store.

A good first step would be to take a long look at your existing structure and determine how it can be modified to affect positive impact on your application.  Additionally, consider a hybrid system at the same time.  Cassandra is great for a lot of things, but if you need a relational system and already are using a lot of Oracle functionality, it likely makes sense for most of your database to stay in Oracle, while moving the pieces that require frequent writes and would benefit from a different structure to Mongo or Cassandra.

Once you've made the decisions about your structure, I would suggest writing scripts/programs/add a module to your existing app, to write the data in the new format to the new data store.  That will give you the most fine-grained control over every step in the process, which in a large system-wide architectural change, I would want to have.

Answer (score 1):

You can also consider using components of Hadoop ecosystem to perform this kind of (ETL) task .For that you need to model your Cassandra DB as per the requirements. 
Steps could be to migrate your oracle table data to HDFS  (using SQOOP preferably) and then writing Map-Reduce job to transform this data and insert into Cassandra Data Model .